# A basic doubt on calculating $E[g(X)]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume $X$ is a continuous random variable and $g$ is a measurable function. Then $g(X)$ is a random variable. Now, there are two ways to calculate $E[g(X)]$.

1) Assume $Y=g(X)$ and find the density of $Y$ from density of $X$ and then calculate $$E[g(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty yf_Y(y)\,dy$$

2) Another approach I see in books is use the formula

$$E[g(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f_X(x)\,dx$$

How to prove that both method is giving the correct result ? Is the question making sense ?

If $X$ is a discrete random variable then I am able to prove it, but when $X$ is continuous then I am stuck.

Comment: Both methods are giving the (same and) correct result. The question is making sense. The proof uses either the standard steps "$g$ indicator function" then "$g$ nonnegative simple" then "$g$ nonnegative" then "$g$ real valued integrable", or the change of variable theorem.

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician

Comment: That Wikipedia article (in its present state) certainly does not answer the question.  It _asserts_ that the two are the same, but the question is how to _prove_ that the two are the same.

Comment: got the proof when $X$ is continuous also.